# How do the following Javascript functions affect the value of 'this'?

Tags: javascript, closures, this, scope

I have an object which has two functions within it, and as I guessed each one has a different value for `this`:

```
custom_controls : {
    play_pause : function () {

        console.log(this); // object

        videoPlayer.getIsPlaying(function (video_is_playing) {
            if (video_is_playing) {

                console.log(this); // window

                videoPlayer.pause(true);
            } else {
                videoPlayer.play();
            }
        });
    }
},
```

Then the function is invoked like this:

`custom_controls.play_pause()`

I've heard that the way you invoke a function denotes the value of `this`.

So my question is: What is happening here? What kind of function invocations am I using? And how does each one affect `this`?

Comment: We don't know how you're invoking the functions, because they're invoked elsewhere.

Comment: i dont know what you try , but if you want to get `this` instance inside other funtion then `var that= this;` then inside other function use `that`

Comment: @KendallFrey I've updated my question with how I invoked the function.

Comment: Good, but it's still missing the invocation of the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `obj.func()`, `this` inside the function will be equal to `obj`. If there is no `obj`, the global object (`window`) is used instead. Or if you are running in [Strict Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it), `undefined` is used.

The first log is your object because you call the function like this:

```
custom_controls.play_pause() // custom_controls will be 'this'
```

The second log is window because the function passed as parameter to `getIsPlaying` is not called with any `this`:

```
videoPlayer.getIsPlaying = function(callback) {
  callback(); // this inside callback will be window
}
```

You can control what the value of `this` will be when you invoke a function by using `call` or `apply`. You can create a new function which will always have the `this` value set to whatever you want by using the `bind` function:

```
videoPlayer.getIsPlaying(function (video_is_playing) {
        if (video_is_playing) {

            console.log(this); // my obj

            videoPlayer.pause(true);
        } else {
            videoPlayer.play();
        }
    }.bind(this)); // magic!
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1):

Your first **this** is referring to `play_pause`.

Your second **this** could either be referring to the Window or your videoPlayer object. In JavaScript, closures and regular functions are 'generally' attached to `window`, and calling **this** returns `window`. In certain cases, e.g. if you attach a function to the click handler of an HTML element, **this** refers to the element...

```
element.onclick = function(){
  this // -> element
}
```

But generally if you just create a `function()`, or have an anonymous one like yours `this` refers to `window`.

```
function hello(){
  this // -> window
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each function is actually executed within a context. That context is denoted as the current `this` for which you call the function.

Given your code:
If you call `custom_controls.play_pause()` you are saying "Take the field of the object custom_controls named play_pause and execute it within the context of the object custom_controls".

Later on calling `videoPlayer.getIsPlaying()` means pretty much the same. Except you're giving it a callback function. How that callback function is executed later on depends on how `videoPlayer.getIsPlaying` is implemented.
If I have to *guess* I'd say that getIsPlaying has a `callback.call(window, video_is_playing)` somewhere in it.

`call` is a method of all function objects in javascript.

There are a few ways to work around this "issue" if you want to reference a `this` in some callback.

```
var self = this;
call_me_maybe(function() {
    console.log(this); //the this that call_me_maybe chose to call your function with
    console.log(self); //the this from the upper scope
});
```

or if you don't care about the object in which context `call_me_maybe` will call your function:

```
call_me_maybe((function(){
    console.log(this); //the this from the upper scope
}).bind(this));
```

What `bind` does is it returns a wrap[per of the function which will *always* be called in the context of the object to which it is bound.
`bind` can also bind arguments as well as the `this` object for the function, creating a sort of curry.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` that you've discovered is the object is what you would expect because the function is operating on that object.

I'm not familiar with your `videoPlayer`, but as the value of `this` is the "window", I would imagine that either A the video player is a function of the browser itself, or B its scope was not properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the "proprietary" of the function, or the object from the function is a method of.

When you define a basic function, the "proprietary" is the page (or the window) itself.

You can check the `callback` documentation for workarounds

Answer (score 0):

When you call `videoPlayer.getIsPlaying` it accepts a callback fn. Callback is invoked directly like `cb()` and hence the context is global (window).

To achieve the callback happening in context of your object. You can use

```
var fn = cb.bind(customControl);
videoPlayer.getIsPlaying(fn);
```

As a rule of thumb when a function is called like `object.function` this is set to `object`. If function is called directly, `this` is set to window. `Function.bind` return a function after binding `object` (this value) optionally along with parameters.

Read: MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind